# why i can't reshape (None, 375) to (25,15) by usint tf.reshape()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

There is a 25*15 image, and i want to identify what it is by using CNN.

When training my CNN, I input a numpy named 'img' as datasets which shape is (200, 375):

```
sess.run(train, feed_dict={X: imgs, Y: labels}
```

This numpy contains 200 sample ,each of them have 375 features.

But when i reshape this numpy to a (-1, 25, 15, 1) Tensor:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 375])
X = tf.reshape(X,[-1,25,15,1])
```

Something wrong happened:

```
Cannot feed value of shape (200, 375) for Tensor 'Reshape:0', which has shape '(?, 25, 15, 1)'
```

I don't know why it can't work, 25*15 is indeed 375.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to reshape the dict variable you are feeding to the placeholder. You have to reshape your img variable as well into shape [-1, 25, 15, 1]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed my code, i reshape my dict variable to [-1,25,15,1], and it works.

Comment: Alright, then please accept the answer so that others can see that your problem has been resolved.